# PMD options not visible in Spring Tool Suite 3.9.6

Tags: java, spring-tool-suite, pmd

I am trying to install PMD plugin STS 3.9.6 based on the Eclipse 4.9.0.

I tried few options already and none of them work:

1. PMD Plugin on the Market Place
2. PMD plugin from the update site: https://dl.bintray.com/pmd/pmd-eclipse-plugin/updates/
3. Installed PMD Plugin manually

But it is not showing PMD option in the context menu, in the project properties and `Window->Preferences`.

Can anybody help on this to configure PMD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PMD Plugin has 2 update sites that are mentioned on the GitHub site (https://github.com/pmd/pmd-eclipse-plugin):

1. Releases (4.0.17.x):
   https://dl.bintray.com/pmd/pmd-eclipse-plugin/updates/
2. Snapshots (4.0.18.x):
   https://dl.bintray.com/pmd/pmd-eclipse-plugin/snapshots/updates/

Releases update site is compatible with Eclipse 4.8.x and it's not compatible with Eclipse 4.9.x

Snapshot update site is compatible with Eclipse 4.9.x but it's not stable.

For now, you can install PMD plugin from the snapshot update site. As soon as it's released, you can reinstall it from the Releases updated site.

Comment: Thank you pavel for resolving my issue

Comment: @pavel Thank you for your inputs.